# How can I elegantly return a map while doing work

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new to Scala, coming over from Java, and I'm having trouble elegantly returning Map from this function.  What's an elegant way to rewrite this function so it doesn't have this awful repetition?

```
    val data = getData
    if (someTest(data)) {
        val D = doSomething(data)
        val E = doWork(D)
        if (someTest2(E)) {
             val a = A()
             val b = B()
             Map(a -> b)
        } else {
           Map.empty
        }
    } else {
        Map.empty
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a problem with connecting too many conditions with `&&`, you can put everything into the natural short-circuiting monad (namely `Option`), perform bunch of `filter` and `map`-steps on it, replace the result by `Map(A() -> B())` if all the tests are successful, and then unwrap the `Option` with a `getOrElse` in the end:

```
Option(getData)
  .filter(someTest)
  .map(doSomething andThen doWork)
  .filter(someTest2)
  .map(_ => Map(A() -> B()))
  .getOrElse(Map.empty)
```

In this way, you can organize your code "more vertically".

Comment: whoa these flavors are totally nuts

Comment: @MedicineMan I'm not sure what this statement was supposed to express, to be honest.

Comment: This code looks nothing like what I originally wrote -- although I'm sure it works, it will take me a little while to parse what's written here.  But it tells me there are far more options to solve this problem than I ever had imagined.

Answer (score 1):

Andrey's answer is correct, but the logic can also be written using a `for` statement:

```
(for {
  data <- Option(getData) if someTest(data)
  d = doSomething(data)
  e = doWork(d) if someTest2(e)
} yield {
  Map(A() -> B())
}).getOrElse(Map.empty)
```

This retains a bit more of the original form of the code, but it is a matter of taste which version to use. You can also put the `if` on a separate line if that makes it clearer.

Note that I have retained the values of `d` and `e` on the assumption that they are actually meaningful in the real code. If not then there can be a single `if` expression that does all the tests, as noted in other answers:

```
(for {
  data <- Option(getData)
  if someTest(data) && someTest2(doWork(doSomething(data)))
} yield {
  Map(A() -> B())
}).getOrElse(Map.empty)
```

Comment: scala is insane

Comment: in the past I have warned against putting too many operations in a single statement.  In Java, we would say that you should break this up for readability: `someTest(data) && someTest2(doWork(doSomething(data)))`    Is scala style different?

Comment: I'm not sure that Scala goes to that level of detail on style. In this case I think the key issue for readability is to give the variables and methods meaningful names so that you understand the purpose of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You may rewrite to take advantage of short circuit, if you are mentioning to the else blocks with Map.empty as repetition.

```
val data = getData
if (someTest(data) && someTest2(doWork(doSomething(data)))) {
  val a = A()
  val b = B()
  Map(a -> b)
} else {
    Map.empty
}
```

Second solution using lazy evaluation:

```
val data = getData
lazy val D = doSomething(data)
lazy val E = doWork(D)

if (someTest(data) && someTest2(E)) {
  val a = A()
  val b = B()
  Map(a -> b)
} else {
  Map.empty
}
```

D, E and someTest2(E) won't get evaluated if someTest(data) is false.

Comment: this is what I had in mind also, but the readability has been compromised by putting so many operations on the second line.

Comment: or you can compute lazyly. lazy val D = doSomething(data) and lazy val E = doWork(D). Then you can still do short circuit and not have to compute(because of lazy eval)  if someTest(data) == false

Comment: Or use local functions.